# Android eclipse sdk is not installing

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Failed to fetch url http://dl-ssl google/android.repository 
I am having this error when I start sdk manager for installing packages. Please help me to resolve this problem. 1 more thing is when I start emulator then it is not starting and my project is not running.

Comment: Eclipse is buggy, switch to Android Studio

Comment: Not entirely sure how to solve your problem but I would say using eclipse in general is going to be a problem considering Google cut support for Eclipse.

Comment: Try switching from http in https. That solved the problem for me sometimes in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do that:

1. Go to Android SDK Manager > Tools > Options
2. Check "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://..."

Answer (score 0):

Please there's  **Android Studio** an Official IDE for Android Development. Check here https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

You will get rid of such problems , Eclipse in Android Development is sometimes Hectic